# Why does the background image css not working?

Tags: html, css, image, url

I don't understand why the image eggs is not showing.

This is the code that used for :

```
.header {
    background: 
    linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92), rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.5) 39.24%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.4)), 
    url("/img/eggs.jpg") center center / cover no-repeat;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Website : https://le-fiasco.netlify.app/
Github : https://github.com/fawraw/lefiasco

Thanks !

Comment: There is a typo on your website `linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92), rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.5) 39.24%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.4)), 
+    url(/img/eggs.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat`. See the extra "+"? Just remove it.

Comment: Thanks Amaury, you are right ! It is now working ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's some problem with relative path of image url,

with exact properties I used some image from online its working fine,

```css
#test{

width : 100px;
height : 40px;
background: linear-gradient(
180deg
, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92), rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.5) 39.24%, rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.4)), url(https://1onjea25cyhx3uvxgs4vu325-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Hello-World_Blog-1536x864.jpeg) center center / cover no-repeat;
    color: #FFF;

}
```

```html
<div id = "test"></div>
```

Comment: I already tested other paths for this img  :

url("/img/eggs.jpg")
url("img/eggs.jpg")
url("../img/eggs.jpg")

It still does not work.